# CSS to target children but to not affect element it is applied to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This may be a stupid question, maybe I have been up too long, but is there any way to add a class to an element and have it affect the elements children only?

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('.parent').append("<div class='child'></div>");
  });
$('#bg').click(function(){
  $('.child').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width: 300px;
  }

.child {
  height:15px;
  width:280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:5px;
  background-color:white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <button id='add'>Add another</button><button id='bg'>Change Background</button>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  </div>
```

Refer to snippet, I need the parent div background color to remain white, but I need to change the css so it affects all future dynamically created div's.

Comment: Yes, but without specifically creating the div dynamically with the class in the append function concatenation, it wont apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the `.parent` div and have it affect the children:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('.parent').append("<div class='child'></div>");
});
$('#bg').click(function() {
  $('.parent').addClass('orange-bg');
});
```

```css
.child {
  height: 15px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.parent.orange-bg .child {
  background-color: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <button id='add'>Add another</button>
  <button id='bg'>Change Background</button>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the .parent.orange-bg .child syntax is exactly what i was looking for. My program is more complex than the example I gave, and I have tonnes of classes and ids, so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the css as follows

```
.parent .child {
   // your css  here
}
```

This css will be applied to all the elements which have a parent with class **parent**.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to affect all children initially, only after the background has been changed. The OP said "all future dynamically created div's"